# Android Studio 2.0 inconsistent location system image

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-2.0

I have downloaded the new Android Studio 2.0 and start buildig my project, but it outputs error like this:

```
Observed package id 'system-images;android-19;default;x86' in inconsistent location 'C:\Android\sdk\system-images\android-19\x86' (Expected 'C:\Android\sdk\system-images\android-19\default\x86')
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This happens when you have old structure of android sdk, to solve this issue put all of the system images of an api version into a folder with name of `default`

Like this:

```
system-image/
       android-15/
             default/
                   x86/
                   armeabi-v7a/
       android-19/
             default/
                   x86/
                   armeabi-v7a/
```

Comment: What do you mean with 'old' structure? When has this changed? Have you found any resources about this?